# How to rectify spring security exception with custom login page?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

Excaption i am getting

> HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

I am trying to implement spring security via custom login page

spring-security.xml

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<!-- <http>
<intercept-url pattern ="/welcome*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
<http-basic/>
</http> -->

<!-- <http>
<intercept-url pattern ="/welcome*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
<form-login/>
<logout logout-success-url="/home"/>
</http> -->
<http>
<intercept-url pattern ="/welcome*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>
<logout logout-success-url="/logout"/>
</http>
<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider>
<user-service>
<user name="rahul" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
<user name="rohit" password="567" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
</user-service>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login Page</title>
<!-- <style>
.errorblock
{
color : #f0000;
background-color : #ffEEEE;
border : 3px solid #ff0000;
padding : 8px;
margin : 16px;
}
</style> -->
</head>
<body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();' bgcolor="blue">
<h3>Login with Username andPassword (Custom page)</h3>

<%-- <c:if test="$SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION !=null"}">
<div class="errorblock">
Your login atempt are not sucessfull,try again
 <br/>Caused : ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message }
 </div>
 </c:if> --%>
<%-- <form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_logout'/>" method="POST">
 --%>
 <form name='f' action='/SpringSecurityApplication/login' method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
<td>User :</td><td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password :</td><td><input type='password' name='password'></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan ='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" ></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan ='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" ></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.springtraining.security.controller;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    public LoginController() {
        System.out.println("LoginController constructor is called ");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model, Principal principal) {
        System.out.println("**********Login Controller is Called********");

        String name = principal.getName();
        model.addAttribute("username", name);
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring Security Custom Form Example");
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(ModelMap model) {

        return "home";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model) {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(ModelMap model) {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginError(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("error","true");
        return "login";
    }

}
```

hello.jsp

home.jsp
I think not required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to submit the crsf token while login (and logout and every other 
POST, PUT, DELETE request).

There are serveral ways to add this to your jsp:

- use spring's jsp `<form:form>` tag (instead the standart form tag) or
- you need to add the crsf token explicit, either by spring security tag `<sec:csrfInput />` or:
- by "standart jsp":

"standart jsp" example:

```
<input type="hidden"
  name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
  value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

@see: Spring Security Reference Chapter [18.4.3 Include the CSRF Token](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-form)

*BTW: I strongly recommend to read the complete [Chapter 18. Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf)*